# Materialize tabs for external links

Tags: html, frontend, material-design, materialize

I'm working with the Materializecss front-end framework and I'm trying to use tabs for moving along external links but it seems like it doesn't work. The examples are for content with a ID inside the same page we're on. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As option - have different active tab on page you're linking. So visiting that page from link automatically sets it as active